# Using $\pm$ to express "in the range of" statement.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Does it make sense to write:

$x =  \left\{A\pm B\right\}$

To mean that $x$ falls in the range of $\left\{A-B,A+B\right\}$?

If not, what would be the correct way of expressing this?

Many thanks!

Comment: $A - B \le x \le A + B$ would work fine, or $x \in [A - B, A + B]$, or $|x - A| \le B$.

Comment: Tehe notation $\{A\pm B\}$  is not idiomatic, and has a different natural interpretation.

Comment: the notion of correctness here really means "well understood by the general mathematical community" there is no harm in one notation over another but the response by @qaphla is what would make sense to someone else if you wanted to share your ideas

Comment: $x=A\pm B$ would probably be understood as $x$ being within that range within a scientific context. Within a math context, though, it's not typical.

Comment: I would (well, should) avoid the ambiguity. In an engineering context one often sees $a \pm b$ used to denote a range as in $[a-b,a+b]$, but the idea is to communicate a target value and a tolerance.

Comment: Many thanks for all the comments - taken on board!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with $\pm$ is that it only refers to two points, not the range between them. Although $x = \{A \pm B \}$ is not commonly seem, I would take it mean that $x$ is $A+B$ or $A-B$.

One popular abuse of $\pm$ is when it's used to mean "approximately". Someone might say that something will happen in "plus or minus three days", and while that precisely means that it will happen three days in the future or it already happened three days in the past, but what they mean is "about three days".

To avoid confusion, the best time to use $\pm$ is when you have two possible answers depending on whether a term is positive or negative, like in the quadratic formula.

Comment: Indeed, the context in which I'm using this comes from an expression from the quadratic formula. The two points produced by applying the formula is a range of interest which I now want to write concisely! Thanks for you help with this.

Comment: But as the other comments say, the rules of mathematical notation are more about what is convenient and easy to understand, and less about what was handed down from Mount Sinai. I don't know in what context you're writing this, but it may be good to write something at the beginning explaining a notation you find concise.

Comment: People are more likely to say, "It will take two weeks, plus or minus three days". Which makes much more sense.